# Determine when branch was merged into another

Tags: git

I've got a small git repo with multimple branches in in

I need to determine when and who has merged particular branch to master.
I use command to see merged branches

```
git branch --merged
```

But I also need to determine when and who did this

**UPDATE ON USING** `git log --merges`

For example i have two branches

- master
- release/1

Execution of `git log --merges` gives me

```
commit 430c9e85e527ab1a63693265e220a8c72ed2fd14
Merge: c5ce3bffc 3ce4f8bff
Author: author1
Date:   Thu Feb 23 07:15:55 2017 +0300

    Merge branch 'master'

commit a909cf5d0100ef1621965f1f4275bd05c1495427
Merge: c2a2a4430 bfda36db3
Author: author1
Date:   Thu Feb 23 05:41:32 2017 +0300

    Merge branch 'feature/3'

commit c5ce3bffc4bde8dc60ae264781e9c990e67daaa1
Merge: 4107e0817 b03ef505f
Author: author2
Date:   Tue Feb 21 11:00:56 2017 +0300

    Merge branch 'release/1' of https://tfs.awesomecode.com/EpicSystems/_git/EPC into release/1

commit b03ef505f177eaf82a31164a97daa1d63c4146f8
Merge: 3f9b75bb7 0ee5e531d
Author: author1
Date:   Tue Feb 21 09:20:31 2017 +0300

    Merge branch 'release/1' of https://tfs.awesomecode.com/epicsystems/_git/EPC
```

So I do not quite undestand what the last two commits from log do.. It's not obvious which one merged release/1 into master

Comment: Unless they performed a rebase, the merge *commit* should have all the information you need.

Comment: Added a bit more information on how to interpret the output of `git log --merges`

Comment: If the answered helped you: Would you consider accepting it? If not, please be so kind and provide more information in order to help us to help you

Answer (score 5):

You can use [git log](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) for that.

While one the `master` branch perform a

```
$ git log --merges
```

to see a log of all merges into `master`.

---

In order to get a better visual understanding of what is going on try out `git log --decorate --oneline --graph`

- `--decorate` will add annotations to the log entries showing informations like `HEAD` and which branch tip this particular commit represents e.g. `origin/release/1`
- `oneline` will produce a more concise representation. Every commit will only show the subject line (you can obviously omit this, but I find it easier to understand the graph this way)
- `graph` will print a graphical representation of your commit history with `*` representing commits and lines to indicate the parents of a particular commit

*The graph will show the newest commit at the top*

---

From here on it's guesswork because I don't know how the history of your repository evolved, but I guess the following:

- I don't really know what the last commit means, because it seems to be missing the `into` part
- The second commit (from the bottom) might come from conflicts between `author2` changes to the `release/1` branch while other changes where made to the same branch. This resulted in the merge of `feature/1` into `feature/1` (some kind of [`git rebase`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) maybe)
- Then `feature/3` was merged
- Then the `master` branch was merged